# Absolute Position of nested ul

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I try to build a horizontal menu. I want absolute positioning of the second level:

> Parent 1 | **Parent 2** | Parent 3
>
> Child 2.1 | Child 2.2

It works in Firefox but not in IE 8, the padding-top is ignored there and the second line overlaps the first one.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/oe8wksax/

Here is the markup:

```
<ul id="#top" class='nav'>
    <li><a href='#'>Parent 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Child 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Child 1.2</a></li>              
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Parent 2</a>
        <ul style="display:block">
            <li><a href='#'>Child 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Child 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Parent 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Child 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Child 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Here the CSS:

```
nav, .nav ul
{
list-style:none;
clear: both;    
}
.nav > li
{
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}
.nav ul
{
position:absolute;
left:5px;
display:none;
padding-top:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  .nav, .nav ul
{
    list-style:none;
    clear: both;    
}
.nav{position:relative;padding: 0;}
.nav > li{margin-right: 15px;}
.nav ul li{margin-right: 10px;}
.nav > li,.nav ul li
{
    float:left;
}

.nav ul
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now Child 2.1 is aligned with Parent 2 (http://jsfiddle.net/oe8wksax/7/). I want Child 2.1/3.1 on the same horizontal position with Parent 1.